# Securing Linux Users

Tags: linux, security, users

I would like to know what is best solution for securing linux user account on application and database server (JBoss, Tomcat, mysql database).Lets asume i have user jboss for running JBossm  and user mysql for database.I use RHELL 5.1, Suse 11 and solaris.What i want to do is basically create a sandbox for each user, so if user jboss will be broken, no data will be corrupted and so on ..

I know i can use SELinux, but i cant find any tutorial for RHEL, that explains restricting user rights for user.

I also know that chroot jail might be the solution, but i am not sure if JBoss application server can run in chroot jail and how to configure it.

The solution, that i am able to use is explicitly restrict acces for each user to every file on filesystem except files dedicated to him (Not nice, i know)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you proposed:

```
Restrict access for each user to every file on filesystem except files dedicated to him
```

is the same idea of chroot. The chroot jail prevents the process from accessing system files except the files inside its new root.

Answer (score 0):

Most processes should work perfectly well inside chroot, as it should be invisible to them - ie they only 'see' the chroot'ed environment as their root environment.